# How to time sinon spies across async tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I have asynchronous tests where a spy is started inside one test and the next test runs while the spy is still wrapped inside the first. This means the `assert(spy.calledOnce)` fails. It's getting called twice;`assert(spy.calledTwice)` passes but erroneously; the `restore()` is not getting called in time.

The spied method `myModule.myMethod` is called inside of `myControler.aMethod`
How can I fix this?

```
it('test one', function() {
  sinon.spy(myModule, 'myMethod')
  myControler.aMethod().then(res => {
    // second test runs before this is called and calls it a second time
    assert(myModule.myMethod.calledOnce)    
    teamController.getAllTeamSlugs.restore()
  })
})
it('test two', function() {
  const fakeCache = {}
  // this runs before the above test can restore the spy
  myControler.aMethod().then(res => {
   // some asserts
  })
})
```

Separate describe blocks do not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by missing `return` statements. The blocks now wait until the correct time to execute. Adding `returns` makes the working code this:

```
it('test one', function() {
  sinon.spy(myModule, 'myMethod')
  return myControler.aMethod().then(res => {
    // second test runs before this is called and calls it a second time
    assert(myModule.myMethod.calledOnce)    
    teamController.getAllTeamSlugs.restore()
  })
})
it('test two', function() {
  const fakeCache = {}
  // this runs before the above test can restore the spy
  return myControler.aMethod().then(res => {
   // some asserts
  })
})
```